# How to prevent sendmail from losing mail when remote host is unreachable

Tags: unix, sendmail, forwarding

I have a small domain with multiple hosts. Sendmail is set up to forward all locally generated mail (mostly mail to `root@localhost` generated by cron jobs) to a central "mail hub", using

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `somehost.mydomain.org')
```

in `sendmail.mc`. Recently I had a problem with the mail server on the remote end, so that It would not accept mail from this host. This caused sendmail to drop all mail. From `/var/log/maillog`:

```
sendmail[3133]: n4461S5s003133: n4461S5t003133: return to sender: Service unavailable
sendmail[3133]: n4461S5t003133: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=34772, relay=XXXXX.org.  [91.184.38.153], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
sendmail[3133]: n4461S5s003133: Losing ./qfn4461S5s003133: savemail panic
```

All mails generated during this time were dropped and lost forever.

How can I prevent this? Ideally I'd like sendmail to try again laiter or eventually to save the mail to a local file as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

Your server almost did the "correct" thing here.

The far end returned a "5xx" class error message, indicating a permanent failure to deliver the message, hence your end aborted delivery completely.

For your server to continue to queue the message it would have had to have received a "4xx" class message, indicating a temporary failure.

To prevent the messages from being lost forever you do however need to identify what caused the "savemail panic" error - they should have just been bounced back to the senders.

Comment: The last paragraph summarizes my problem: both senders and recievers are local accounts, for which somehost.mydomain.org is the final destination (says "MAIL_HUB").

I'm starting to assume the "MAIL_HUB" option is only suitable for setups where either the mail hub for a domain is guaranteed to be up, or it's ok to lose local mail on the other hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, `sendmail` should save any failed send attempt locally in spool files and retry for up to five days, so probably there is some configuration error.  According to these references:

- [savemail panic in sendmail](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/savemail_panic_in_Sendmail.html)
- [sendmail: savemail panic](http://rackerhacker.com/2008/02/18/sendmail-savemail-panic/)

you need to make sure that you don't have (from above references):

- Missing postmaster alias in `/etc/aliases`
- Hard disk is full
- The mail spool for the postmaster has the wrong ownership
- The `mbox` file for the postmaster is over 2GB and `procmail` can’t deliver the e-mail

Additionally, ensure that you're not running into an `selinux` issue.  It may be that `selinux` is preventing `sendmail` from saving the file.  EMail should never be totally lost -- at worst it should be bounced to the original sender and to postmaster.  If EMail is totally lost, it's either a configuration error or a bug in sendmail.

What this error means, in context, is that `sendmail` tried to deliver the message in spool file `./qfn4461S5s003133` but the remote mail server returned the error response "Service unavailable."  Thus, the local `sendmail` attempted to bounce the EMail.  Something went wrong while trying to do so, so the EMail was abandoned.

This is the EMail equivalent of a CPU's double bus fault.  That is, a fatal error (not being able to save or bounce the EMail message) occurring in response to a fatal error (the remote server being unavailable for long enough that sendmail gave up retrying).

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me to the right direction. The problem is that "MAIL_HUB" sets the destination for all local mail (including mail tor root or postmaster). So sendmail does indeed seem to do the right thing. Perhaps I need to rethink my configuration.